# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll asp.net-mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stack-overflow

I'm getting the following runtime error in a view of an ASP.NET MVC application:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Right before `return View();` everything is fine. And in the view I got hardly any code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

@(Html.EJ().Schedule("Schedule1", 
                     (Syncfusion.JavaScript.Models.ScheduleProperties)ViewBag.Model))
```

But it's this line where the exception is being thrown. I don't see anything suspicious in `ViewBag.Model` either.

How can I debug this error? The stacktrace is empty.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and start stepping -- you should be able to observe something in your code causing a recursive loop towards the stackoverflow condition.

Comment: And what does @(Html.EJ().Schedule("Schedule1", Syncfusion.JavaScript.Models.ScheduleProperties)ViewBag.Model)) do ?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar It creates a Syncfusion schedule. http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/js/default.htm#!documents/createyourschedulein1.htm

Comment: http://www.syncfusion.com/forums/118267/stackoverflow-exception

Comment: @DavidTansey The trouble is that everything being called here runs inside third party code.

Comment: @DavidTansey, wasn't that a bit too obvious to do in the first place? I was very explicit by saying that it happens right after that line I pasted in my question. There is nothing to step in. After that it's end of story. JLRishe, that might be it, can you post that as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thread on the [Syncfusion support forum](http://www.syncfusion.com/forums/118267/stackoverflow-exception) suggests that the issue is caused by having unobtrusive validation enabled. If you can disable it, that might be your best bet. Otherwise, they propose this rather verbose workaround:

```
@(Html.EJ().Schedule("Schedule1")

        .Width("100%")

        .Height("525px")

        .CurrentDate(new DateTime(2014, 6, 1))

        .ScheduleClientSideEvents(even=>even.CellClick("onCellQuickWindowClose").AppointmentClick("onAppQuickWindowClose"))

        .CategorizeSettings(Fields => Fields.Datasource((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.categorize).Enable(true).AllowMultiple(false).Id("id").Text("text").Color("color").FontColor("fontColor"))

        .ContextMenuSettings(menu => menu.Enable(true).MenuItems(item => item.Cells(ViewBag.cell).Appointment(ViewBag.app)))

            .AppointmentSettings(fields => fields.Datasource((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.datasource)

            .Id("Id")

            .Subject("Subject")

            .StartTime("StartTime")

            .EndTime("EndTime")

            .Description("Description")

            .AllDay("AllDay")

            .Recurrence("Recurrence")

            .RecurrenceRule("RecurrenceRule")

            .Categorize("Categorize"))

)





<script type="text/javascript">

    function onCellQuickWindowClose(args) {

        var dialog = $("#Schedule1AppointmentQuickWindow").data("ejDialog");

        dialog.close();   // Here we are closing the quick appointment window

    }

    function onAppQuickWindowClose(args) {

        var dialog = $("#Schedule1AppDetailsWindow").data("ejDialog");

        dialog.close();   // Here we are closing the quick appointment window

    }

</script>
```

That thread also provides the following download link to get the code shown above:

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ScheduleNuget-2089236857.zip